# How can I get a user to input a duration into an HTML5 web form without annoying them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, user-experience

My users need to enter a duration in Days, Hours and Minutes.

Right now I've just implemented this as three fields which is okay and works, but which is not exactly a nice bit of design. The alternative is to just have 1 field and let them type `2 days, 3 hours, 45 minutes` or `15 m`, or `1d 2h 35m` or `90m`, or `2 days`, etc. That seems like it would need some non-trivial parsing to get really right, and be complex to internationalise.

What are some 'best practice' examples of a web UI component that allows the user to enter a length of time simply?

Please note this is not a `DatePicker`, but a duration input component.

Comment: does your context lend itself to any frequently chosen durations? maybe you pair a text field with a drop down, so I can type 90, and choose "minutes"...you can type 1.5, and choose "days"...etc

Comment: That could be a solution. Maybe an auto-completion that trains the user to input in a specific way.

Comment: or just keep an eye on the drop down option picked most often, and have that be the default, so that only some users need to modify it?

Comment: Your question seems to cover two topics. Technically how to accomplish what you looking to do or is it based on the UI and whats presented to the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After considering the feedback here I decided to implement a single form field with a terse input style and some smart parsing.  See http://jsfiddle.net/davesag/qgCrk/6/ for the end result. Improvements are of course welcome.

```
function to_seconds(dd,hh,mm) {
  d = parseInt(dd);
  h = parseInt(hh);
  m = parseInt(mm);
  if (isNaN(d)) d = 0;
  if (isNaN(h)) h = 0;
  if (isNaN(m)) m = 0;

  t = d * 24 * 60 * 60 +
      h * 60 * 60 +
      m * 60;
  return t;
}

// expects 1d 11h 11m, or 1d 11h,
// or 11h 11m, or 11h, or 11m, or 1d
// returns a number of seconds.
function parseDuration(sDuration) {
  if (sDuration == null || sDuration === '') return 0;
  mrx = new RegExp(/([0-9][0-9]?)[ ]?m/);
  hrx = new RegExp(/([0-9][0-9]?)[ ]?h/);
  drx = new RegExp(/([0-9])[ ]?d/);
  days = 0;
  hours = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  if (mrx.test(sDuration)) {
    minutes = mrx.exec(sDuration)[1];
  }
  if (hrx.test(sDuration)) {
    hours = hrx.exec(sDuration)[1];
  }
  if (drx.test(sDuration)) {
    days = drx.exec(sDuration)[1];
  }

  return to_seconds(days, hours, minutes);
}
```

Comment: A small note: Add * to the day regex if you want the days to exceed 9 like this: new RegExp(/([0-9]*)[ ]?d/);

Comment: If you use "[0-9]+" instead of "[0-9][0-9]?" then you allow inputs of more than double digit days, hours and minutes. Like 222h will also work

Answer (score 3):

Things to consider:

- how broad a range of possible inputs do you expect? e.g. is it likely that one user will enter "10 days" and the other "2 minutes"?
- do you want efficiency or first-time intuitive behavior? some applications are not directly intuitive, but with training can be more efficient to use than their "easier" counterparts.
- do your users prefer keyboard or mouse, and how proficient are they? a data entry pro will have different needs/wants than a "two-finger typist".

Of course, there is no one correct solution. Few options:

- Remember the new (HTML 5) input type="range" and input type="number" available in many browsers. Range often displays as a slider (despite its name, it isn't necessarily used to input a range); number displays as a numeric up/down with specifiable increments. This may ease data entry.
- 3 drop down lists (one for days, hours, minutes) may be the most foolproof option if you expect a broad range of inputs. This also has complete browser support, doesn't rely on any JavaScript, will be predictable on major mobile devices, etc.
- If you have common durations (e.g. 90 minutes, 2 hours, 4 hours), you might present a single dropdown with those durations specified and an "advanced" button which allows more granular specification for the exceptional cases.

Comment: My users are much more likely to enter x minutes, (up to 90 minutes I'd say), or n hours, x minutes (up to 48 hours I'd say), and rarely y days, n hours, x minutes (more likely either 48 hrs, or 2 days.  Never more than 9 days. My users are already typing a bit anyway, so, having thought about it (and your post was very helpful btw as was Robot Woods in comments above, so thanks,) so I'm currently experimenting with a simple input field that autocorrects based on what it can work out from the input.

Comment: See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davesag/qgCrk/5/) for an example of what I've come up with so far.

Comment: @DaveSag - I like your example, and it's pretty intuitive even for a first-time user. It's similar in nature to functionality offered by http://www.datejs.com/ (see the demo where you can enter date offsets), so there is an existing precedent for this type of UI.

Comment: If you have frequent/regular users, I think they will find it to be an efficient way to enter the data (no keyboard/mouse switching), low number of keystrokes, no mouse travel, completes onblur.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [**jQuery Datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

If you don't want to directly select a date, you can tweak it in your context to get a length of time.

Comment: Sorry but there is no magic design bullet that will turn a date picker into a duration editor. I have of course already looked at DatePickers and so forth but what I am looking for is a UX solution not a plugin to hack that was chosen simply because you thought `oh he wants something with days in it, I know, a DatePicker.`

Comment: I completely understand your situation. You should include that detail in your answer otherwise I was under the assumption that you hadn't already tried to implement it as a duration selector.

Answer (score 0):

Think of what people already know for a date and/or time selection. The behavior pattern has already been set for you. You just need to follow it. Think about what's being done on a mobile device. From there you can leverage the pattern.

Take a look at: http://mobiscroll.com/
It has a ton of features and with some minor tweaking it looks like you could get it to do what you need.

Using something like this from a UX standpoint will also make your app seem more familiar to users as it's a common pattern they already understand.